# Evitar que mi aplicación se abra 2 veces

Tags: c#, asp.net

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto el cual consiste de un **login** y una pagina donde "muestra" las **variables de sesión** (ya que están ocultas para el usuario).

Lo que quiero conseguir es que la pestaña `Mostrar.aspx` al estar activa y yo habrá una pestaña nueva con el mismo nombre me arroje un mensaje de que ya esta activa la pestaña.

adjunto código de ejemplo:

**Login.aspx:**

```
 protected void ButtonLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        string s= System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AppComintecConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection(s);

        conexion.Open();
        string query = "SELECT * FROM Usuarios where usuario = @username and contrasena = @password";
        SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand(query, conexion);
        cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", TextBox1.Text);
        cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", TextBox2.Text);


        //Si existe un usuario con los datos retorna true, caso contrario false
        var reader = cm.ExecuteReader();

        if (reader.Read())
        {
            //Si existe, Bienvenido...

            Session["nombre"] = reader["nombre"].ToString();
            Session["id_usr"] = reader["id_usr"].ToString();
            Session["area"] = reader["area"].ToString();
            Session["tipo"] = reader["tipo"].ToString();
            Session["permiso"] = reader["permiso"].ToString();
            Session["mail"] = reader["mail"].ToString();
            Session["puesto"] = reader["puesto"].ToString();
            Session["sede"] = reader["sede"].ToString();
            Response.Redirect("Mostrar.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            LabelError.Visible = true;
            LabelError.Text = "usuario o contraseña invalido !!";
            LabelError.Attributes.Add("class", "alert alert-danger");
        }

        conexion.Close();
    }
```

**Mostrar.aspx**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["nombre"] == null || Session["id_usr"] == null || Session["area"] == null || Session["tipo"] == null || Session["permiso"] == null || Session["mail"] == null || Session["puesto"] == null || Session["sede"] == null)
        {
            Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            resultado1Label.Text = Convert.ToString(Session["nombre"]);
            resultado2Label.Text = Convert.ToString(Session["id_usr"]);
            resultado3Label.Text = Convert.ToString(Session["area"]);
            resultado4Label.Text = Convert.ToString(Session["tipo"]);
            resultado5Label.Text = Convert.ToString(Session["permiso"]);
            resultado6Label.Text = Convert.ToString(Session["mail"]);
            resultado7Label.Text = Convert.ToString(Session["puesto"]);
            resultado8Label.Text = Convert.ToString(Session["sede"]);

            LabelAcept.Text = "Claramente estan cargadas las variables de sesion";
            LabelAcept.Attributes.Add("class", "alert alert-success");
        }
    }
```

Alguien podría ayudarme un poco respecto al tema?

Answer (score 0):

En tu program.Cs podrías utilizar:

```
private static void Main()
        {
            System.Threading.Mutex mutex = new System.Threading.Mutex(false, "MyUniqueMutexName");
            try
            {
                if (mutex.WaitOne(0, false))
                {
                    // Run the application
                    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
                    Application.Run(new FrmNombreX());  //En nombre X va el nombre de tu Frm Principal o la vista que estes mostrando en tu cargada. 
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Ya me estoy ejecutando!"); //El Sms que tu le quieras colocar
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (mutex != null)
                {
                    mutex.Close();
                    mutex = null;
                }
            }
        }
```

El anterior código verifica que entre las tareas que se estén corriendo, no se este ejecutando ya tu programa.

Comment: Que tal coloque el código que me muestras, pero me arroja error en las lineas donde se encuentran la palabra **Application**
Podrías orientarme un poco acerca de esto?

Comment: Claro, que error te aparece?

Comment: Que tal, el error me sale en donde esta la palabra Application, ya que yo lo estoy realizando para asp.net, podrias orientarme un poco en cuanto a como realizarlo pero entorno a asp.net por favor